# Cannot resolve method setListAdapter

Tags: android, adapter, android-adapter, listadapter

Am fairly new to android and am getting this error in my android studio I need help.
i get error cannot resolve method `setListAdapater(com.ippc.mobileapp.adapter.HotelAdapter)` and cannot resolve `this.getListView()`

// This is a section of my code

```
public class Hotelinfo extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hotelinfo);


    final List<Video> data = getHotels();

HotelAdapter adapter = new HotelAdapter(this, data);

setListAdapter(adapter);

    this.getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos,
                                long arg3) {

            launchWebActivity(data.get(pos).getUrl(),   data.get(pos).getTitle());
        }

    });
```

Comment: What type of activity are you extending?

Comment: @UdiIdan  public class Hotelinfo extends AppCompatActivity

Comment: @UdiIdan, i have updated my code also

Comment: @UdiIdan tnks, it worked!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you extended AppCompatActivity, which doesn't inherit from ListActivity, you can't use setListAdapter().

You need to add the ListView to your layout and then use ListView.setAdapter().

```
yourListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```